# Error Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined even after spying

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to spy on a subscribe but getting error Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined. The subscribe I am testing is in the loadChildComponent method

```
this.componentRef.instance.closeModal.subscribe(() => this.closeModal());
```

In my test method I am doing

```
 spyOn(component.componentRef.instance.closeModal, 'closeModal').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
```

The spy seems to be incorrect.

```
fit('should call destroy ', () => {
    let childFixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
    childFixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    component.componentRef = childFixture.componentRef;
    spyOn(component.componentRef.instance.closeModal, 'closeModal').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
    spyOn(component.componentRef, 'destroy').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnDestroy();
    expect(component.componentRef.destroy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Component

```
export class ModalDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private readonly _onClose = new Subject<any>();

  public componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
  public childComponentType: Type<any>;
  public onClose = this._onClose.asObservable();

  // add this:
  @ViewChild(InsertionDirective, { static: false })
  insertionPoint: InsertionDirective;

  constructor(public componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              public cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
              public dialog: ModalDialogRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadChildComponent(this.childComponentType);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
  }

  onOverlayClicked(evt: MouseEvent) {
    // close the dialog
  }

  onDialogClicked(evt: MouseEvent) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }

  loadChildComponent(componentType: Type<any>) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
    const viewContainerRef = this.insertionPoint.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    this.componentRef.instance.closeModal.subscribe(() => this.closeModal());
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.dialog.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scope of your `spyOn` statement. Currently it's targeting `closeModal` of `closeModal` (extra `closeModal`) which doesn't exist and therefore is not stubbing/mocking that function correctly:

```
spyOn(component.componentRef.instance, 'closeModal').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
```